# Why would gradle not download from maven central?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, nexus, maven-central

For some reason gradle is not downloading dependencies from Maven Central. We have a private Nexus repository set up as well and for some reason gradle is looking there for dependencies and not Maven Central.

I get a ton of errors similar to:

```
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 400 Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 1.5.0.RELEASE: http://*****/repository/******/io/pivotal/spring/cloud/spring-cloud-services-dependencies/1.5.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-services-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom]
```

I swear I have resolved this before when I first set it up, but cannot replicate. In order for me to hit Maven Central, I must have the proxy set up and have Nexus as an exclusion to the proxy.

This all works locally, but the issue comes in when dealing with Jenkins and the Sonarqube plugin. Locally I've tried various proxy settings (remove systemProps or even system env variables), but errors are not the same (ie cannot find host).

Any idea why it's not able to download from Maven Central?

---

Update:
So I was able to narrow it down a little further. When using Jenkins and Sonarqube `withSonarQubeEnv` block, something happens with how gradle resolves dependencies. See 3 examples:

```
// #1 This breaks when SNAPSHOT is declared first
repositories {
    maven {   // <------------------ SNAPSHOT
        credentials {
            username usr
            password pass
        }
        url uri(snapshot)
    }
    maven {   // <------------------ RELEASE
        credentials {
            username usr
            password pass
        }
        url uri(release)
    }
    mavenCentral()    // <---------- Maven Central
}


// #2 This works since mavenCentral() is first:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()    // <---------- Maven Central
    maven {   // <------------------ SNAPSHOT
        credentials {
            username usr
            password pass
        }
        url uri(snapshot)
    }
    maven {   // <------------------ RELEASE
        credentials {
            username usr
            password pass
        }
        url uri(release)
    }
}


// #3 This also works because no failing version policy:
repositories {
    maven {   // <------------------ RELEASE
        credentials {
            username usr
            password pass
        }
        url uri(release)
    }
    mavenCentral()    // <---------- Maven Central
}
```

This works fine when not using `withSonarQubeEnv` in Jenkins. Why would order matter when using `withSonarQubeEnv`?

Comment: Is this a SonarQube issue? Try using Jenkins without SonarQube and share that result.

Comment: @JeroenHeier That was a good idea. I ran `build` instead of `sonarqube` gradle task and received the same errors. I think it has something to do with the `withSonarQubeEnv` setup. I assumed that the proxy settings were being dropped, so I added `withEnv` inside it and had no changes. I also checked the gradle daemon logs to see the proxy environment variables were set, and they were. Also, I added a gradle task to see the gradle.properties proxy settings were still there, and they were. No idea why adding `withSonarQubeEnv` causes this. Any ideas?

Comment: My setup is similar to the **SonarQube Scanner for Gradle** section in this link: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It had nothing to do with `withSonarQubeEnv` block in Jenkins. The [Sonarqube sample settings for gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline) had the `--info` flag added, which I was using for testing. I added that to my build step and found same errors. I even cleaned the cache in the .gradle folder and everything still downloaded.

I suppose Gradle does something a little misleading when it tries to resolve dependencies. It spits out info messages when retrieving a **RELEASE** artifact from a **SNAPSHOT** repository, but it still continues to retrieve the artifact from the other listed repositories.